# Alguém pode me explicar a lógica de funcionamento desse padrão

Tags: engenharia-de-software, scheme

Eu estou escrevendo um compilador Scheme R6RS(trabalho escolar). Ele está funcionando perfeitamente com exceção desse padrão proposto no próprio manual em [`11.19 - Macro Transformes: sintaxe-rules`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.19).

Eu já li e reli e não consigo entender como que esse padrão de elipses(... ...) pode retornar o elemento 4 da lista (1 2 3 4 )?

**Código que não consigo entender o funcionamento:**

```scm
(define-syntax be-like-begin
  (syntax-rules ()

    ((be-like-begin name)

     (define-syntax name

       (syntax-rules ()

         ((name expr (... ...))

          (begin expr (... ...))))))))

(be-like-begin sequence)

(display (sequence 1 2 3 4))
```

O resultado é:

```
4
```

Alguém me por favor me explique o por que desse resultado. É o que me falta para fechar um capitulo da minha vida.

Comment: Eu já testei em alguns compiladores e uns não reconhecem esse padrão, mas os que reconhece o resultado é sempre 4.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia por favor explicar o motivo do porque essa pergunta é ruim pois essa questão é relativa ao minha monografia onde escrevi um compilador da [linguagem SCHEME R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_start) em C# e esse padrão de expansão é único que não consegui compreender e é o que me impede concluir o compilador e aqui está o [link na documentação oficial para esse padrão de expansão](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.19)

Comment: Outra ótima pergunta para https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

A questão está no begin expr:

begin expr (... ...)

As expressões no seu exemplo, no caso os números (1, 2, 3 e 4) são avaliados sequencialmente da esquerda para a direita, e no caso o resultado é o próprio numero em si (... ...)=template(ellipsis ellipsis), sendo que todos são ignorados com a exceção do último.

Você pode alterar sua sequencia como for, o resultado sempre será o último numero.

Comment: Eu não quero saber o exp faz eu quero saber o BNF para montar a arvore de sintaxe abstrata que compreenda esse padrão. E exemplo mostra exp mas pode ser qualquer outra função em seu lugar.Veja http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.19

Comment: Mas a questão não é o exp mas sim o begin, veja: "Scheme begin expressions aren't just code blocks, though, because they are expressions that return a value. A begin returns the value of the last expression in the sequence." https://www.cs.utexas.edu/ftp/garbage/cs345/schintro-v14/schintro_18.html#:~:text=Scheme%20begin%20expressions%20aren't,like%20begin%20s%20as%20well.

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver. Estou escrevendo um compilador eu preciso do [BNF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalismo_de_Backus-Naur) para usar no [Bison](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) de forma que eu possa gerar uma [AST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_sint%C3%A1tica_abstrata) para compilar o código que o usuário digitar. Se o usuário digitar esse transformador meu compilador não entende. Ele entende toda a linguagem menos esse padrão de expansão de macro.

Comment: Essa que citou é definida aqui http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.4.7 foi um dos primeiro não terminais que fiz.

Comment: Por exemplo se testar esse código no [Racket](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-racket-online/) funciona sem problemas mas se testar no [BiwaScheme](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/DeepskyblueUnsungTaskscheduling#main.scm) vai dar erro porque o autor do compilador está com o mesmo problema que eu, que é não compreender a lógica desse padrão de transformador de macro.

Comment: Não é que eu seja chato ou implicante. As vezes estou escrevendo outra resposta e não a dou a devida atenção. Obrigado por se interessar pelo meu problema.

Comment: Tranquilo. Talvez fosse interessante então você explicar o que acontece quando tenta compilar esse código no seu compilador. Se nem chega a compilar ou se a execução é que fica errada.

Comment: Não cheguei a criar os símbolos não terminais para essa produção, [veja o parser](https://justpaste.it/306n1), pois não faz sentido. Todos os elementos de linguagem estão funcionais menos essa produção o que torna o meu compilador em um compilador de brinquedo pois não cria macros higiênicos.

Comment: Explicando porque sua resposta não responde a pergunta, onde se encontra os "..." ele pode ser expandido na forma `(<pattern> ...) ou
(<pattern> <pattern> ... . <pattern>) ou
(<pattern> ... <pattern> <ellipsis> <pattern> ...) ou
(<pattern> ... <pattern> <ellipsis> <pattern> ... . <pattern>) ou
#(<pattern> ...) ou
#(<pattern> ... <pattern> <ellipsis> <pattern> ...)`  mas no manual diz que é uma abstração sintática mas não há uma explicação pontual do que. O que deixou perdido, eu cheguei sim  a fazer uma tentativa mas os resultados davam valores divergentes do esperado.